why nftables prerouting chain make ssh connected failed
This is my nftables config file.
#/bin/sbin/nft -f
flush ruleset
table inet my_fw_tables {
    chain input_filter {
            type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
            ct state {established,related} accept
            ct state invalid drop
            iif lo accept
            tcp dport 7749 counter accept
            ip protocol icmp accept
    }
    chain dnat_prerouting {
            type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat;policy drop;
             tcp dport 80 dnat ip to 192.168.100.1:80
    }
    chain output_filter {
            type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }

}
When I reload the configuration,I cannot connect to ssh, if I make the chain "dnat_prerouting" policy "accept", then I can connect. why?

check out the networking packet flow diagram - what do you think happens if you drop everything?

I probably should just comment, unfortunately I'm not reputable enough ;]
Your dnat_prerouting chain should definitely utilize accept policy.
Regards
Mike
